# a simple person class in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm starting to learn objective c, I made a simple person class, i get 6 errors,
expected specifier-qualifier-list before '-' token

just wondering if someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong,

thanks

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>


@interface Person:NSObject
{
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;


    -(void) setFName:(NSString *) theFirstName;
    -(void) setLName:(NSString *) theLastName;
    -(void) printName;
}
@end

@implementation Person
{

    -(void) setFName:(NSString *) theFirstName
    {
        firstName = [[NSString alloc]initWithString: theFirstName];
    }

    -(void) setLName:(NSString *) theLastName
    {
        lastName = [[NSString alloc]initWithString: theLastName];
    }

    -(void) printName
    {
        NSLog(@"The person's full name is",firstName,lastName);
    }

}

@end


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];

    [person setFName:@"Amir"];
    [person setLName:@"Karimian"];
    [person printName];

    [person release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not declaring `firstName` and `lastName` using `@property`?

Comment: Also, you could set the first and last names in an initialiser.

Comment: And, since you mention iPhone, there is no memory management code. The autorelease pool doesn't affect your Person class because you haven't autoreleased anything. Get used to thinking about memory management now, or you'll have problems with it later.

Comment: @Abizern, thanks for the suggestion, appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method declaration will be outside of closing brace.

```
@interface Person:NSObject
{
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;
}

-(void) setFName:(NSString *) theFirstName;
-(void) setLName:(NSString *) theLastName;
-(NSString *) firstName;
-(NSString *) lastName;
-(void) printName;

@end
```

And in implementation no brace is required.

```
@implementation Person
// { is not required
-(void) setFName:(NSString *) theFirstName {
    // code
}

-(void) setLName:(NSString *) theLastName {

}

// in this way

// } is not required
@end
```

There are at least two logical errors. In printName

```
NSLog(@"The person's full name is %@ %@",firstName,lastName);
```

Your format string was wrong.

And in main

```
[person setLName:@"Karimian"];
```

You have user "ser" instead of "set".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, all the errors are gone now but when I run the program I'm still not getting the person's full name, is there any reason why?

Comment: Probably because of this typo `[person serLName:@"Karimian"];`

Comment: Have you fixed the typo? What are you getting?

Comment: fixed the error but I'm still not getting the full name. dont know why?

Answer (score 6):

Or even simpler:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * lastName;

- (NSString *) fullName;

@end

@implementation Person
@synthesize firstName, lastName;

- (NSString *) fullName {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self firstName], [self lastName]];
}

- (void) dealloc {
  [self setFirstName:nil];
  [self setLastName:nil];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the header file:

```
@interface Person:NSObject
    {
        NSString *firstName;
        NSString *lastName;
    }


    @property(retain, nonatomic) NSString * firstName;
    @property(retain, nonatomic) NSString * lastName;

    -(void) setFName:(NSString *) theFirstName;
    -(void) setLName:(NSString *) theLastName;
    -(void) printName;

    @end
```

In the implementation use the @synthesize to create your getter and setter accessor
methods:

```
@implementation Person

/* Create the getter and setter properties
   which are also called accessor methods
*/
@synthesize firstName = _firstName;
@synthesize lastName = _lastName;

//The other methods
-(void) setFName:(NSString *) theFirstName{
}
-(void) setLName:(NSString *) theLastName{
}
-(void) printName{
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, apart from taskinoor's answer, it's good practice to implement a -(void)dealloc method in your class:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [firstName release]; //since they have been alloced.
    [lastName release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Note that if you wanted to use properties, like Dave DeLong, you should be careful about choosing `@property(assign)`, `@property(copy)` or `@property(retain)` and managing whether you release the NSStrings or not.