# Objective-C: Relating NSStrings to each other?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very new to code in general and I'm in the process of learning Objective-C, so I apologize in advance if I phrased this question incorrectly.

I have created several arrays with this goal in mind:

- Show how many people there are and tell their names
- Show how many cities there are and tell their names
- Assign people to cities and calculate the populations

I have completed that task, but I have assigned each person individually to the array for each city. Is there a way that I can simply relate the NSStrings? For example "blockCity = bill, bob, jim" instead of creating a new array for populations?

```
// My people

    NSString *bill = (@"Bill");
    NSString *bob = (@"Bob");
    NSString *jim = (@"Jim");
    NSString *kevin = (@"kevin");
    NSString *stacy = (@"stacy");
    NSString *cooper = (@"Cooper");

    NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: bill, bob, jim, kevin, stacy, cooper, nil];


        NSLog(@"Here are my people: %@", people);
        NSLog(@"I have %lu people", [people count]);

// My places

    NSString *blockCity = (@"BlockCity");
    NSString *hyperCity = (@"HyperCity");
    NSString *pixelTown = (@"PixelTown");
    NSString *nowhere = (@"Nowhere");

    NSMutableArray *cities = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: blockCity, hyperCity, pixelTown, nowhere, nil];

        NSLog(@"Cities: %@", cities);
        NSLog(@"There are %lu cities", [cities count]);

//populations

   // BlockCity population
    NSMutableArray *bcpop = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: bill, bob, jim, nil];

        if ([bcpop count] == 0) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is abandoned.", blockCity);

        } else {

            NSLog(@"%@ has a population of %lu", blockCity, [bcpop count]);
        }

    //HyperCity population
    NSMutableArray *hcpop = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];

        if ([hcpop count] == 0) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is abandoned.", hyperCity);

        } else {

            NSLog(@"%@ has a population of %lu", hyperCity, [hcpop count]);
        }

    //PixelTown population
    NSMutableArray *ptpop = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: kevin, stacy, cooper, nil];

        if ([ptpop count] == 0) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is abandoned.", pixelTown);

        } else {

            NSLog(@"%@ has a population of %lu", pixelTown, [ptpop count]);
        }

    //Nowhere population
    NSMutableArray *npop = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];

    if ([npop count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is abandoned.", nowhere);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"%@ has a population of %lu", nowhere, [npop count]);
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can make a collection of objects without using a `[thing thingWithObjects:this, that, nil]` style method call?

Comment: Yes, I am basically attempting to simplify the code for populations.

Comment: Well, then the answer is not really, no. Objective-C is notoriously verbose, so much so that it's essentially self-documenting. While on one hand this makes line lengths get a little out of control sometimes, it also makes the code easier to read, because it tells you exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way you can just “relate the NSStrings”.<sup>1</sup>

The appropriate thing to do here is to start thinking about your design in an object-oriented way.

What are the different sorts of objects in your program?  There are people, so a `Person` class is appropriate.  Give the `Person` class a `name` property (an `NSString`).

There are cities, so a `City` class is appropriate.  Give the `City` class a `name` property (an `NSString`), an `inhabitants` property (an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` to be filled with references to `Person` objects), and a `population` method (returning `unsigned long`) that returns the number of inhabitants.

Once you have all that, you can even give `City` a `populationDescription` method that returns the string description of its population, like this:

```
- (NSString *)populationDescription {
    if (self.population == 0) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is abandoned.", self.name];
    } else {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has a population of %lu", self.name, self.population);
    }
}
```

---

Footnote 1.  For the pedants: associated objects don't count.  They are not appropriate for this and they are too advanced for a learner at this level.

Comment: Rob, you need a reference to `self.name` in the second line of your `populationDescription` method.  Kyle, this can get you started on code for a `Person` class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4491259/1445366

Comment: @robmayoff thank you very much for the explanation. This definitely puts me on the right track. I learned the basics of C before moving to Objective-C, so objects are a new topic for me. I appreciate the kind feedback.

Comment: @AaronBrager that is great additional feedback and thank you for providing the link.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use `NSMutableDictionary` in this case to relate people with their city. Something like:

```
NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: bill, bob, jim, kevin, stacy, cooper, nil];
NSMutableDictionary *cityWithPeople = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[cityWithPeople setObject:people forKey:@"CityName"]; // to add people related to that city

NSArray peopleInCity=[cityWithPeople objectForKey:key]; // return array of people in city
```

Also [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088872/how-to-use-nsdictionary) here to know how to use `NSDictionary`